# suspend and resume alamofire download request - large file

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swift5, alamofire-request

I'm using Alamofire to download large files in my ios project.
When i cancel a download request (that is currently downloading a large file to disk) - this request produces `resumeData` with the data downloaded so far - but I would like a `responseURL` with the URL of the file with the partially downloaded data. I plan to use the responseURL serializer at the end to never load the entire data in memory - but if I want to suspend and resume downloads - then this is forcing me to load the data in memory.

there's a `fileURL` in the download request - but the documentation states that this is populated after the download has finished.

any pointers/suggestions would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [explained on GitHub](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/3434), `resumeData` only includes the data necessary to resume a download, not the actual download data itself, so it's perfectly safe to keep it around in memory. You can parse the value to get the `URL` of the partially downloaded data, but it's not a formatted encoding, so it's not really appropriate for Alamofire to parse it directly.